# Is there a trace in RAM(Random access memory) of keyboards input?

Tags: windows

I lost some notes and i have about 40 minutes before my pc will restart.
I know it might be imposible but anyway maybe i will learn something.
So the question goes:
Is there a RAM trace left by keyboard input that could be recovered in 40 minutes or less.
I use Win 7 build 7100.
edit: the browser is Chrome, anyone knows how to dump ram  RAM?
I search but cant find

Comment: I search something to dump ram, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see for yourself how impossible this is, download [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). Go to Extras > Open RAM > chrome.exe > OK, and look around Chrome's memory yourself.

Answer (score 4):

No, keyboard input does not leave a reliable residue in RAM. While it's possible that the RAM used by the application that crashed (I'm assuming this is what happened) might not yet be overwritten, it's highly unlikely that you'll be able to get anything useful out of it.

Comment: Thanks. I used Chrome browser from google, any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sorry.  The only way you can get that level of persistence from a RAM trace is to [cryogenically freeze the RAM](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/security/cryogenically-frozen-ram-bypasses-all-disk-encryption-methods/900), and that's only good for about 20 minutes.

Comment: :) so now i got about 38 minutes+20minutes + cost of liquid nitrogen

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, since keyboard presses usually pass by the USB and they are handled by the USB controller in a way that is not predictable. There is not direct mapping between a keyboard and the memory.

If you assume that they are stored somewhere in your RAM you should check all the bytes of used RAM without any clues.. not feasible

You should have used something like a keylogger..

Comment: Yeah ,Keylogger would be fine. Is there a of mapping: 
keyboard->windows-> ram

Comment: @Chris: A keylogger doesn't do anything after the fact.